# Displaying Objects in HTML using Angular2

Tags: json, angular

In my component i am getting the json in the variable name peopleDetails

Sample JSON:

```
{
   name:'xxxx',
   age:123,
   details:{
      qualification:'abc',
      yearofPassing:1111
   }
}
```

I tried to display it in my html like this

```
<div>{{peopleDetails.name | async}}
```

But i cant able to get the property of the json

It is printing the whole json when i tried like this.

```
<div>{{peopleDetails.name | async | json}}
```

But i want to access all the properties of the Json.

Comment: Why are you using `| async`?

Comment: Because i am selecting it from the store

Comment: It's not valid JSON, it should be {
   name:'xxxx',
   age:123,
   details:{
      qualification:'abc',
      yearofPassing:1111
   }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell from your question what the problem is.
A guess:

```
<div>{{(peopleDetails | async)?.name}} </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain me why we are accessing with question mark

Comment: To prevent an error when `(peopleDetails | async)` returns `null`, because `null` doesn't have a `name` property https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator